# Firebase cloud functions - schedule notification 5 times a day based on times stored on realtime database

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a database structure that looks like this:

[image: Database structure]

What I want to achieve is the following:
I want to fire a notification to everyone subscribed to a topic ( this I can do ), but I can’t figure it out how to do the following:

- Using cloud functions to read these times on database
- after that using Schedule to send notifications on these specific times everyday with its description (name)
- Make sure whenever I change the times on database, the Shedule will also be updated

Is that possible to achieve ? Thank you

Comment: the salat time will be slightly different for each area right ? do you want to make dynamic push notification ?

Comment: why not fetching the data once a day from Real Time Database to the client ( let say Android),  and then create local notification from device ?  if you want to send push notification from server, IMO you need to make a cron job using cron scheduler. but it will be expensive since each user for each area will have slightly different salat time right

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I detected a problem with that approach, what if I change the time on database and the user don't open the app, lets say for 2..3 days..? he will be receiving old timings

Comment: Actually this is timings for a mosque in a particular city... so its only one area with these 5 timings. Thanks

Comment: I think if you change the salat time in realtime database you have to use cloud function triggers like in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DglTSNEdl0U, when it is triggered then you send Firebase Cloud Messaging to Android app bringing updated data, like in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydcMY4J3tJI, so you can update the value stored locally in the app to then make local notification. you can make it to not show up the notification when sending FCM in Android, just silent update.

Comment: Hello, I found this official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages). I can see that if you want to use "Notification message" you have to set the notification key.